# Error event listener not handling load resource errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, http-status-code-404, addeventlistener

I looked everywhere but I couldn't find something that helped. This has been really annoying me because I actually tested what I was doing a few weeks ago and it worked then.

So here's my code:

```
var error_handler = function(e) {
    console.error(e);
    e.preventDefault();
}
window.addEventListener('error', error_handler);
```

And that works for handling errors, but it's not handling errors like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

when I wrote the code before, it did pick up those errors. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this error message occurring before the page loads?

Comment: And what is throwing the 404? Does not appear to be a JavaScript error.

Comment: @bflemi3 No, the event listener is able to pick up errors that occur before it.

Comment: @epascarello It's a JavaScript Error, it's happening because I'm trying to load a script that doesn't exist. The error itself doesn't bother me, I know exactly what's causing it, what I care about is having an error handler for picking it up.

Comment: Is the resource referenced in the `head`?

Comment: Loading a script file is not really a JavaScript Error.

Comment: @bflemi3 Yes it is.

Comment: This all probably pertinent info to add to your question. One more question from me... Are you trying to dynamically load the script or is it hardcoded in the `head`?

Comment: @bflemi3 Sorry, should have been more specific. Yes, scripts are dynamically loaded in our system.

Comment: @Jertyu Please add this info to your question. You're more likely to get an answer that's accurate.

Answer (score 2):

When a resource (such as an `<img>` or `<script>`) fails to load, an error event using interface Event is fired at the element that initiated the load, and the onerror() handler on the element is invoked. These error events do not bubble up to window, but can be handled with a `EventTarget.addEventListener` configured with `useCapture` set to `true`.

For more details refer this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `error` event does work for resource loading errors, you just need to set `useCaputure` to `true`

```js
window.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
  console.log('error: ', event);
}, true);
```

You will not get the status code or text of the network response, but you will have an event that shows you the target that throws the error.
For example:

```
> error: Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: img, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 1, …}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading an external file is not a JavaScript error so it is not going to be caught unless the error comes from the script file from trying to be executed. You can add an error event to the script tag, but you are not going to get the error message from it.

```js
function handleError(evt){
  console.log(evt);
}

var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.src="error.js";
scr.onerror = handleError
document.body.appendChild(scr);
```